# How do I read the seven segment font(OCR)?

Tags: .net, .net-core, ocr, tesseract, seven-segment-display

I have been working on extracting text from images, specifically focusing on seven-segment fonts,
using .NET. Unfortunately, my attempts with popular libraries like Tesseract and IronOcr have been
unsuccessful, as they seem to excel with normal English fonts.

Here's a brief overview of my approach so far:
**1. Tesseract**: Limited to normal English fonts, unable to recognize seven-segment characters.
**2. IronOcr**: Similar limitations, not suitable for seven-segment fonts.

Despite these efforts, I'm facing challenges in accurately extracting text from images with
seven-segment fonts.

Link to : [Image Dataset Folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1b4S-UQbxaXZPbDfOkTiC1m0qTIt6fdb7?usp=sharing)

Additionally, I've experimented with image processing techniques, including:

- Cropping and zooming to the text region.
- Applying gray, black and white, and binarization filters.

Comment: I experimented with the [letsgodigital](https://github.com/arturaugusto/display_ocr) tesseract recognition data, and that didn't seem to help.

Comment: letsgodigital was training on digits + E , so it will not recognize degrees and C correctly.